# Deploying a SPA - Config files for different environments and git

Tags: git, webpack, vue.js, environment-variables, vue-cli

Currently creating a vue.js SPA using vue-cli's webpack template.

I have multiple environments:

- Dev
- Staging/QA
- UAT
- Production

I have an API URL which is specific per environment and is used throughout the application. I have only developed for Dev and QA so far. My current process is:

1. Develop using `webpack-dev-server`
2. Stop webpack-dev-server, run `yarn run build`
3. Add all changes to git, commit and push on QA branch
4. Pull on QA Staging server

This works fine because QA is treated as my 'production' right now, and webpack builds everything I need.

Now I have UAT and Production to build for, with different API URL's. I can't figure out a logical git workflow/process here.

Am I supposed to merge my feature branch into the respective environment git branch and then run `yarn run build`?

I can't quite find any examples out there of using Git/SPA/Webpack and environment variables to not have a messy git history.

Comment: Why don't you just run the build command on the environment rather than on your machine?

Comment: If the build process somehow fails - then what? I would rather let the QA team test the exact build and files that will go to production rather than building on the environment. Maybe my thinking is wrong and this is actually the solution? Is it common practice to do this?

Comment: We used to have a docker container for our Vue App. Each environments pipeline would just pull the code from git, build a new container from the docker file, install npm inside it, run the build command and then serve the built files from the built directory.  I don't see why, when using a container, the build process should fail when it compiles on local in the container, or why it should produce any other outcome than the exact same container on local. I'm not claiming this is the only correct way, if there's any, but it worked for my team.

Comment: Thanks for the contribution. Didn't think of using a container besides on dev. I'll look into this option for now. It's strange that I can't find many people online talking about their deployment strategy involving this.